# Lagrange multipliers- local maximum, minimum or a saddle point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

There is the function $f(x,y,z)= z^{2}-yz-xz+z-2xy-2y+x^{2}+2x$ and the constraint function given by: $g(x,y,z)=3z-3y+z-1$. Find the conditional extremum of $f.$

The Lagrange function is given by:

$F(x,y,z, \lambda)=f(x,y,z)+\lambda \cdot g(x,y,z)$

So the necessary condition:

\begin{cases}g(x,y,z)=0 \\ \nabla f= \lambda \nabla g  \end{cases}

The solution is given by $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$

How to check whether the point $(1,1,1)$ is a minimum, maximum or a stationary point? I mean how the sufficient conditions in this case are expressed.

Comment: I don't find $(1,1,1)$, but maybe there's a typo? Perhaps you didn't mean $g(x,y,z)=3\color{red}{z}-3y+\color{red}{z}-1$?

Comment: Oh maybe, generlally the solution of this set of equations isn't really a problem. Given any solution (x,y,z) how to find out whether this point corresponds to max, min or a saddle point? That's the case I want to know.

Comment: When no simple (e.g. geometric or algebraic) arguments are possible, you can use the [bordered Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian).

Comment: Yeah, I know, but this method is very  time-absorbing. What do you think about that schematic procedure like in here http://prntscr.com/ezw1ec. If z >0, then this point corresponds to a conditional minimum, if z<0 maximum, if z=0 then it's a saddle point. I think, that's way faster method than the first one.

Comment: @Heisenberg can you point me towards a reference for that result? Also, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574500/second-order-conditions-for-constrained-optimization) for sufficient conditions

Answer (score 0):

In this case, with

$$
\cases{
f(x,y,z) = z^2 - y z - x z + z - 2 x y - 2 y + x^2 + 2 x\\
g(x,y,z) = 3 z - 3 y + z - 1 = 0
}
$$

the condition for stationarity gives

$$
\cases{
2 + 2 x - 2 y - z = 0\\
-2 - 3 \lambda - 2 x - z = 0\\
1 + 4 \lambda - x - y + 2 z = 0\\
- 3 y + 4 z - 1 = 0
}
$$

and solving we obtain

$$
(x,y,z,\lambda)^* = \left(-\frac{60}{133},\frac{41}{133},\frac{64}{133},-\frac{10}{19}\right)
$$

now, as the restriction is actuating, we can eliminate $y$ from

$$
\cases{
u = z^2 - y z - x z + z - 2 x y - 2 y + x^2 + 2 x\\
3 z - 3 y + z - 1 = 0
}
$$

thus obtaining

$$
u =  \frac 13(2 + 8 x + 3 x^2 - 4 z - 11 x z - z^2)
$$

now calculating the hessian for $u(x,z)$ we have

$$
H_u = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -\frac{11}{3} \\
 -\frac{11}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

with eigenvalues $\left\{\frac{1}{3} \left(2+\sqrt{137}\right),\frac{1}{3} \left(2-\sqrt{137}\right)\right\}$ which qualifies the stationary point as a
saddle point,

Answer (score -1):

the type of point is given by the Hessian matrix definiteness.
From this article, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) the rules are:
"If the Hessian is positive definite at x, then f attains an isolated local minimum at x. If the Hessian is negative definite at x, then f attains an isolated local maximum at x. If the Hessian has both positive and negative eigenvalues then x is a saddle point for f. Otherwise the test is inconclusive. This implies that at a local minimum the Hessian is positive-semi-definite, and at a local maximum the Hessian is negative semi-definite."

Comment: This second derivative test is not applicable to the constrained problem.