# Second Order Conditions For Constrained Optimization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having trouble understanding the second order conditions for deducing whether an extreme value of a function subject to constraints is a minima or a maxima. I'll put forth what I do understand. Please fill in the gaps.

Suppose I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with constraints $g_\ell : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g_\ell = C_\ell$ for $\ell \in [m]$. Consider the Lagrange Function:
$$\Lambda(\textbf{x},\lambda) = f(\textbf{x}) - \sum_{\ell=1}^m\lambda_\ell[g_\ell(\textbf{x}) - C_\ell]$$
Let $(\textbf{x}^*,\lambda^*)$ be a solution to $\nabla \Lambda(\textbf{x},\lambda) = \textbf{0}$. Then $\textbf{x}^*$ extremizes $f$ subject to the constraints $g_\ell$ with $\ell \in [m]$. Next, if we consider

$$\textbf{H}_\Lambda(\textbf{x},\lambda) = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \lambda^2} & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \lambda \partial \mathbf x} \\
\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \lambda \partial \mathbf x}\right)^{\mathsf{T}} & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \mathbf x^2}
\end{bmatrix}
 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &\ldots & 0 & -\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} &  \cdots & -\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_n} \\[1.5ex]
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\[1.5ex]
0 &\ldots & 0 & -\dfrac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_1} &  \cdots & -\dfrac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_n} \\[1.5ex]
-\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_1} &  \cdots & -\dfrac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial x_1\, \partial x_1} & \cdots  & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial x_1\,\partial x_n} \\[1.5ex]
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots &\\[1.5ex]
-\dfrac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_n} &  \cdots & -\dfrac{\partial g_m}{\partial x_n} & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial x_n\, \partial x_1} & \cdots  & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial x_n\,\partial x_n} \\[1.5ex]
\end{bmatrix}$$
So we can rewrite this as
$$\textbf{H}_\Lambda(\textbf{x},\lambda) =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial \mathbf x} \\
-\left(\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial \mathbf x}\right)^{\mathsf{T}} & \dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \mathbf x^2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

> Suppose $\textbf{r}(t) \in g^{-1}(\textbf{C})$ with $\textbf{r}(t^*)=\textbf{x}^*$ and $\textbf{r}'(t^*) = \textbf{v}$, then
> $$\left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \textbf{v}^T \left(\frac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \textbf{x}^2}\right) \textbf{v}$$

**Proof**:
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(\textbf{r}(t)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(\textbf{r}(t))}{\partial x_i} r'_i(t) \longleftarrow \text{ By Chain Rule} \\
\implies \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \left.\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial f(\textbf{r}(t))}{\partial x_i}\right|_{t=t^*} r'_i(t^*) + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(\textbf{x}^*)}{\partial x_i} r''_i(t^*) \leftarrow \text{ By Product Rule}\\
\implies \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \sum_{i,j \in [n]} \frac{\partial^2 f(\textbf{x}^*)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} r'_i(t^*) r'_j(t^*)+ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f(\textbf{x}^*)}{\partial x_i} r''_i(t^*) \\
\implies \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \textbf{v}^T \textbf{H}_f \textbf{v} + \nabla f(\textbf{x}^*) \cdot \textbf{r}''(t^*) $$

$$\implies \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \textbf{v}^T \textbf{H}_f \textbf{v} + \sum_{\ell = 1}^n\lambda_\ell \nabla  g_\ell(\textbf{x}^*) \cdot \textbf{r}''(t^*) \tag{$\dagger$} \label{eq1}$$

Now performing a similar calculation for $g_\ell(\textbf{r}(t)) = 0$ who's derivatives must be $0$ gives us:

$$0 = \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} g_\ell(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \textbf{v}^T \textbf{H}_{g_\ell} \textbf{v} + \nabla g_\ell(\textbf{x}^*) \cdot \textbf{r}''(t^*) \\
\implies - \lambda_\ell \textbf{v}^T \textbf{H}_{g_\ell} \textbf{v} = \lambda_\ell\nabla g_\ell(\textbf{x}^*) \cdot \textbf{r}''(t^*)$$
Substituting this in \ref{eq1} gives us:
$$\left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \textbf{v}^T \textbf{H}_f \textbf{v} - \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_\ell \textbf{v}^T \textbf{H}_{g_\ell} \textbf{v} \\
\implies \left.\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} = \textbf{v}^T \left(\textbf{H}_f - \sum_{i=1}^n \textbf{H}_{g_\ell} \right)\textbf{v} = \textbf{v}^T \left(\frac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \textbf{x}^2}\right) \textbf{v}$$

Now if $t^*$ is a maximum (or minimum), we should have $\left.\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} f(\textbf{r}(t))\right|_{t=t^*} \leq 0 \; (\geq 0)$ with strict inequality if it's a strict maximum (or strict minimum) which translates to $\textbf{v}^T \left(\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \textbf{x}^2}\right) \textbf{v} \leq 0 \;(\geq 0) \; \forall \, \textbf{v} \in \text{null } \dfrac{\partial g(\textbf{x}^*)}{\partial\textbf{x}} $, once again with strict inequalities for strict maxima (or minima).

Now of course this will always be true if $\left(\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda}{\partial \textbf{x}^2}\right)$ is negative (or positive) definite. 
Q1. Is it also true in the cases where it is semidefinite (why/why not)? 
Also, it seems like definiteness is a much stronger than required condition since we only really need to show definiteness restricted to the set $\text{null } \dfrac{\partial g(\textbf{x}^*)}{\partial \textbf{x}}$.
Q2. Is there a quick and easy way to check definiteness on the restricted set? 
Q3. I also don't understand how this translates to restrictions on signs on on the sequence of leading principal minors of $\textbf{H}_\Lambda$ which is what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Bordered_Hessian) suggests. Could someone write me a proof?

Comment: Consider the unconstrained problem of minimizing $f(x)=x^{3}$ at $x=0$.  The second derivative is $0$ at $x=0$, but it is neither a min nor max.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Brian Is this understanding correct? If we consider $\Lambda(\textbf{x}) = \Lambda(\textbf{x},\lambda^*)$ as a function of $\textbf{x}$ and find it's taylor polynomial about $\textbf{x}^*$, we get: 
$$
\Lambda(\textbf{x}) - \Lambda(\textbf{x}^*) = \sum_{1 <|\alpha|\leq k} \frac{\partial^\alpha \Lambda(\textbf{x}^*)}{\alpha!} \textbf{v}^\alpha  + \sum_{|\alpha|=k+1} h_\alpha(\textbf{x})\textbf{v}^\alpha, \\
$$ with $\textbf{v} = \textbf{x}-\textbf{x}^*$.

Comment: Continuing: If $\textbf{H}_\Lambda$ is semidefinite then $\exists \textbf{v}_\circ \neq\textbf{0} :\frac{\partial^\alpha \Lambda(\textbf{x}^*)}{\alpha!} \textbf{v}_\circ^\alpha = 0$ which means the sign of the LHS depends on the 3rd order term. Since the sign of $(k\textbf{v}_\circ)^\alpha$ for $|\alpha| = 3$ depends on $k \in \mathbb{R}$, this means the LHS can be greater than or less than $0$ no matter how small of a neighbourhood around $\textbf{x}^*$ we choose and therefore $\textbf{x}^*$ can't be an extremum. If the 3rd order terms disappear, we can continue to look at higher order terms